# Assert cannot be resolved to a type - Eclipse Helios for RCP Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

The following error is preventing my project from running:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
  assert cannot be resolved to a type
  Syntax error on token ".", ; expected
  The method holdsLock(Logging[]) is undefined for the type Logging
  at org.geotools.util.logging.Logging.getLogging(Logging.java:183)
  at org.geotools.util.logging.Logging.getLogging(Logging.java:170)
  at org.geotools.util.logging.Logging.<clinit>(Logging.java:78)
  at myproject.RasterTest.<init>(RasterTest.java:57)
  at myproject.RasterTest.main(RasterTest.java:318)`
```

The logging tool needed from the `geotools` library has many `assert` statements within the classes which eclipse does not recognise.

I have seen a few similar problems on **SO** which suggested entering the string `-ea` into
 `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> jdk1.7.0_51 -> Edit -> Default VM Arguments`, but I did that to no avail.

The line which throws the error:

```
public class RasterTest extends ViewPart {
  ...
  protected final Logger LOGGER =  
    org.geotools.util.logging.Logging.getLogger("org.geotools.factory");
  ...
}
```

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problems" means there's a problem *before* you even try to run your code. Look for Errors in the Problems View.

Comment: I did check the Problems View which only shows "Assert cannot be resolved to a type" and flags it as an error throughout the library's classes.

Comment: Maybe it's time to show us the problematic code?

Comment: From everything I've read, it seems to be an Eclipse/Java problem where the compiler is not recognising the "assert" type. Even in an empty class, if I try to "assert" something, the word "assert" is being flagged as an error. Just like when using a variable without declaring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Instead of entering the string `-ea` into
`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> jdk1.7.0_51 -> Edit -> Default VM Arguments`

I entered the string `-ea` into
`Right Click on ProjectName in Project Window -> Run as -> Run Configurations -> ProjectName.product -> Arguments -> Default VM Arguments`.

If anyone knows why the second works, but not the first, I'd love to know why.

Comment: But how is this fixing a compile-time problem?

Comment: Because the compiler is reading "assert" as an undeclared variable, rather than a type. The compiler was treating the string "assert" the same as "abcdefg". Just a meaningless word. "-ea" tells the VM to enable asserts so the compiler will know what it means.